# How to wrap text inside react-native-material-menu MenuItem?

Tags: react-native

I use `react-native-material-menu` to display a search auto-complete.
I'm trying to wrap the text inside MenuItem so the totality of the address is shown, now it is cut.
Here is my implementation:

```
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Menu
        button={<View />}
        style={{...styles.menu, backgroundColor: props.appTheme.SECONDARY_BG}}
        ref={menu}>
        {dataSource.map((item, index) => {
          return (
              <MenuItem
                style={styles.menuItem}
                key={index}
                onPress={() => handlePressSearchItem(item)}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    color: props.appTheme.DEFAULT_FONT_COLOR,
                    flexWrap: 'wrap',
                    flex: 1,
                  }}>
                  {item.place_name}
                </Text>
              </MenuItem>
          );
        })}
      </Menu>
    </View>
  );

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {},
  menu: {
    width: '86%',
  },
  loadingItem: {
    marginLeft: 20,
  },
  menuItem: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'center',
    maxWidth: '100%',
  },
});
```

Here is a screenshot of the current result:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap ?

Comment: I'm not sure we can use `overflow-wrap` in react-native.

Comment: ohh sorry for that, didn't pay attention that it is for react-native

Comment: It's ok no worries.

Comment: Why not create a `View` that wraps the `Text` and set the `width` of that `View` to `100%`

Comment: @Harrison i tried to put the text inside a `View` but the text does not show on the menu. In the doc it says `Children must be based on <Text> component (like text itself, strings, react-native-vector-icons or expo icons) otherwise you may get an error on a real device.`

Comment: @B. Mohammad what about in the `Text` styles set `flexShrink: 1`

Comment: @Harrison, sorry didn't work.